# How to render ocean wave using opengl in 3D?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, rendering

How to render ocean waves using opengl in 3D? Any reply will be welcome.

Edit:

Is there any source code that renders ocean waves but not using an other sdk or api? It's difficult to learn how render it by read OSG source code maybe. So any tutorials about it will be ok, it is very good that it attach the source code.

Comment: This question is just too broad to be answered properly (without just a simple link to some website that is probably found faster by google), as we don't even know what you can do and have tried already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Christian (above) is right. Currently your question is very broad and difficult to answer. You might want to do some research yourself and then ask a more targeted question.

Start looking at [shallow water equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations) for example. (I'm skipping full fluid simulations here for the moment) Or read Tessendorf's "[Simulating Ocean Waves](http://graphics.ucsd.edu/courses/rendering/2005/jdewall/tessendorf.pdf)". Or have a look at [Cem Yuksel](http://www.cemyuksel.com/)'s wave particles. Even if you don't end up implementing any of it, the references will be a good resource for you. Another one might be [this collection of links](http://vterrain.org/Water/).

Not really a clear answer, but give us more to go on and we can point you in a more specific direction.

Answer (score 7):

Rendering realistic looking water is *extremely difficult*. Luckily there are tools to make it easier, like [OSGOcean](http://code.google.com/p/osgocean/), which can render some quite impressive waves.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer to this question.

Comment: The OSGOcan project has moved to github : https://github.com/kbale/osgocean